# get json value from php loop

Tags: php, arrays, json

how can I get the same results/values in one loop rather than two?

```
$json = file_get_contents($url) 
$data = json_decode($json, true);


$desc = $data["descriptions"];
$assets = $data["assets"];

foreach ($assets as $assItem) {
    echo $assItem["assetid"];
}


foreach($desc as $descItem) {
    echo descItem["name"];
}
```

I've tried something like

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo $item["assets"]["assetid"];
    echo $item["descriptions"]["name"];
}
```

pastebin to the json: https://pastebin.com/raw/uA9mvE2e

Comment: I have deleted my answer as the question is not clear. Paste `var_dump($data)` and expected output. So that we can help you better.

Comment: post the json file format

Comment: added pastebin to the json in main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($data['assets'] as $k => $item) {
    echo $item["assetid"];
    echo $data["descriptions"][$k]["name"];
}
```

This assumes that `$data['assets']` and `$data['descriptions']` share the same indices.